# How do I externally call a method within a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a way to call a method defined in a jQuery plugin directly in my script?

update

```
(function($){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {   
    return this.each(function() {

      function doSomething() {
        // do something
      }

      function doSomethingElse() {
        // do something else
      }

      doSomething();
      doSomethingElse();
    });
  }
})(window.jQuery);
```

now i want to call doSomethingElse() from my script. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: hope this link help http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-call-a-method-on-a-plugin-once-it-s-attached

Comment: Plugins usually use closures and give public access to only some variables (options) that need to be changed as per requirement which means that the methods are usually private and cannot be called from outside. But by introducing new options, you can extend or modify the plugin as per your requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is, "no".  As posted, that code *explicitly* hides those functions from the outside world.

One jQuery-ish way to make those functions available is to define them differently. Personally, I like to create plugins that have a corresponding "global" object, so if I have

```
$.fn.pointy = function() {
  // plugin
}
```

I'll also have:

```
$.pointy = {
  something: function() { ... },
  somethingElse: function() { ... }
}
```

That's nice for providing both relevant utilities and also configuration APIs. Thus you could put your "doSomething" functions there, and then use them inside your plugin by qualifying the names as `$.myPlugin.doSomething()`.  Of course you can also *create* the functions inside your plugin initialization, so that they might be closures with access to *other* private functions.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion best is to use event system when you nedd to call it from outside.
Here is the result with your code:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {   
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.on('doSomething', function() {
        // do something
      }

      $this.on('doSomethingElse', function() {
        // do something else
      }

      $this.trigger('doSomethingElse');
      $this.trigger('doSomething');
    });
  }
})(window.jQuery);
```

or call it from outisde with same method:

```
$('.myPluginDiv').trigger('doSomethingElse');
$('.myPluginDiv').trigger('doSomething');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure i get you, but after defining a new function you can still cal it outside of the jQuery Selection, see:

```
 $.fn.myfunc = function(){
   alert('foo');
 }
 $.fn.myfunc(); // works
 $('#something').myfunc(); // works too
```

So you would have to find out exactly how the methods needs to be called and then do it via `$.fn.func()`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use events so the plugin is listening for an event with bind and then you call trigger. Could be a target like window etc.